# Android Gradle Library(Atifact) Publication Using Bitbucket

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, bitbucket, dsl

It's been hours and I'm stuck trying to publish/release signed artifacts on Maven Central using bitbucket.
I did the same using groovy but now i have migrated from groovy to Kotlin DSL and now gradle version is 7.0.0.